# SMB female connection on breadboard

Tags: connector, breadboard

I was just wondering if someone knows if it is possible to conveniently place a SMB female connector onto a standard breadboard.

From the specs, it seems to match, but I just want to be sure before the purchase.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a continuation to your previously deleted question. You seemed to falsely assume that the only connection to these signals is via SMB connector, so please open up the eval board manual to see that the same signals are conveniently accessible on other connectors too. So you do not need SMB connectors, the other interfaces can be used as well.

Comment: interesting breadboard ... where did you get it? ... where did you get the picture?

Comment: you could mount the SMB connector on a small carrier board that would plug onto the breadboard

Comment: The ground tabs will most likely be too thick for the breadboard. If it fits you might damage the connectors inside the breadboard (bend them). Also depending on what signals are going through the SMB it is possible they won't maintain integrity on a breadboard+jumpers.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for your comment. I have searched the eval board datasheet, but could not find another connection possibility. If you have seen it, would you mind pointing me towards that part in the manual? Many thanks.

Comment: @Justme Oh, you might be right... I found a schematic of the board, and it seems like the SPI signals are branched off to the SMB plugs, but also continue to another connector.

Comment: @Justme Yes, it seems that the values are also easily accessible through the SDP standard connector.

Comment: @Justme Actually, as you were saying before, the red test access points is probably the simplest solution!

Comment: @jsotola I just took this as an image from the internet: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/371195194271706009/

Comment: @henry Honestly, if a problem's solution actually requires an RF connector like SMB, you can be almost certain breadboard *can't* be part of that solution. So, as Justme recommends: really understand which signals you need to use, from where, and how to transport them. I'll be honest, at this point it feels like you've settled on "I need to plug an SMB connector into breadboard" before you've even described – to yourself nor to us – what technical requirement you're actually addressing!

Comment: @henry thanks for info ... i did not know that such a breadboard existed ... btw, pinterest links to https://www.86duino.com/?p=95  .... also found something similar... google `STEMtera`

Comment: For putting low frequency SMA/SMB cables onto a breadboard I usually just cut the cable in half and put regular pins on it.  This is bad at high frequencies, but putting very high frequencies onto a breadboard isn't going to work anyway.

Comment: Mechanical compatibility aside… a breadboad has horrible parasitic capacitance, any signal which would need a coax would be influenced by it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pins as described, squares pins of 0.03" seems too big for a standard breadboard. It may not fit in the plastic holes and if it does it will probably stretch out the spring leafs of the connectors. It is bigger than the average 0.025" or smaller standard headers, and breadboards are more suited for round pins. The center pin seems like its the same size but might be bigger.

The rest seems like it would fit, based on center to center spacing, taking up a 9 x 9 square of breadboard holes.

If you really need a smb connector you are better off using a pigtail to a standard header or breakout board. As breadboard have high capaticence and noisy for most RF or high speed signal purposes, you might as well make it easy to plug in without damaging the board and having to troubleshoot bad connections.

Comment: If you are using the connector for power or non RF or high speed data, there are better suited connectors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!